# Подсчет контрольной суммы наподобии CRC16 на Python

Tags: c#, python-3.5, битовые-операции

Всем привет! 
Знаю, что в Python довольно проблемно производить битовые операции. Но у меня есть кусок кода на C#, который нужно переписать для Python 3
вот код на С#

```
//Initial value of CRC

#define _CRC_INIT_VAL 0xE295


//CRC16 calculation

// Should be called for each byte in sequence

//

// Arguments:

// unsigned short crc - CRC16 before next step of calculation

// unsigned char byte - next byte

//

// Return: updated CRC16

//==========================================================================================

static unsigned short CRC16(unsigned short crc, unsigned char byte)

{

  unsigned short carry;



  carry = 0xFF & ((crc >> 8) ^ byte);

  carry = carry ^ (carry >> 4);

  return ((crc ^ (carry << 4) ^ (carry >> 3)) << 8) ^ ((carry ^ (carry << 5)) & 0xFF);

}
```

Вопрос - как такую же ф-ю переписать на Python?

Comment: Понять как в Питоне делаются битовые операции и переписать. Вариантов немного...

Comment: Дело в том, что на выходе мне нужно получить 2 байта... Почему то в своих изысканиях я на выходе получал либо слишком много байт, либо целое число(при первых попытках).

Comment: Дело в том, что вы не поняли как это работает.

Comment: Дело в том, что вы ведете полемику. Естественно я не разобрался как это работает! Если бы я смог самостоятельно разобраться - не задавал бы вопросы. Собственно, как и любой задающий здесь вопросы человек.

Comment: И в чем тогда вопрос? Переписать за вас? Тут такое не приветствуется.

Comment: Владимир, покопавшись в заданных вами вопросах - вам переписали и не раз. Это во-первых.
Во-вторых, не надо переписывать. Знаете ответ - круто! Натолкните на размышления в нужную сторону? объясните, почему у меня получались неправильные результаты, хотя должно было получиться почти стандартное CRC16? Весь нюанс тут в том, что побитовые операции в Питоне не работают, поэтому дают на выходе целочисленные значения. Подсчет CRC в библиотеке CRC идет за счет таблицы заранее подсчитанных значений, а мне такой вариант не годиться

Comment: Вы где-то не там копались, скажу сразу. Почему ваш код работает не так, не видя кода сказать нельзя, это два. Побитовые операции в Питоне прекрасно работают и дают на выходе целые как и должны, это три. О том, что вам надо с ними разобраться вам сказано было с самого начала. Почему не годится табличный вариант - не понятно, если он дает тот же результат, к примеру. Попробуйте корректно сформулировать вопрос.